# Android How to create a "flat" instead of dynamic ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

Is it possible to reuse an ExpandableListView to create views without iterate an array or even create an adapter?

Follow my scenario:

I have a static number of information to display to the user. The UI/UX team asks to implement an effect exactly like an ExpandableListview. But looks like the list components are more suitable when we have dynamic data to display.

In my case it's only two blocks of views that should be displayed using a vertical accordion effect, exactly like an ExpandableListView.

I'm wondering if there are an easier way to archive this effect since I have a static data to display.

Any guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to reuse an ExpandableListView to create views without iterate an array or even create an adapter?

You certainly need an `ExpandableListAdapter`, as that is the way that `ExpandableListView` knows what the parent `Views` look like, how many children there are in each parent, and what those children `Views` look like. Just because your data is "static" does not mean that `ExpandableListView` knows how to display it, any more than a Web browser knows, on its own, how to display static JSON as Web content.

Whether you can get away without "iterate an array", you are welcome to try classes like `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`, or see if there is some third-party `ExpandableListAdapter` that can conveniently map your "static data" for you.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare
The SimpleExpandableListAdapter will suit well to my situation.